# How to add and remove function to after-save-hook for specific major mode?

Tags: elisp, hook, major-mode

I wrote a simple major mode for a configuration file.
I would like to check the syntax upon saving.
How to make sure the `my-check-syntax` is added to `after-save-hook` iff it is under `my-config-mode`.

```
(defun my-check-syntax ()
  ;; code: print a message to show whether syntax is correct
  )

(define-derived-mode my-config-mode nil "my-config"
     (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(my-config-font-lock-keywords))
  ;; (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'my-check-syntax)
  )

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.myconfigure\\'" . my-config-mode))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LOCAL` argument to `add-hook` and `remove-hook`.